# Pulling Single digit out of string --bash

Tags: regex, bash, parameters, grep

Example

./test.sh R19

```
echo "$1" > test.txt 
cat test.txt | grep -o ^[A-Z] > model.txt
cat test.txt | grep -o [0-9] > num1.txt
cat test.txt | grep -o [0-9]$ > num2.txt

echo "$(cat model.txt)00$(cat num1.txt)00$(cat num2.txt)"
```

Im expecting to see R001009, however what i get is

R001
9009

So how can i get it so my num1.txt only recieves the middle number and not both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `grep -o '[0-9]'` is returning *all the digits* on separate lines.

The painful way would be `cat test.txt | grep -o [0-9] | head -1 > num1.txt`

But don't do that: you're doing **way** too much file I/O. Use a regex in bash:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9])([0-9])$ ]]; then
    printf "%s00%d00%d\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
fi
```

Make sure you're using `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang line.

---

```
$ set -- R19
$ if [[ $1 =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9])([0-9])$ ]]; then
>     printf "%s00%d00%d\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
> fi
R001009
```

Comment: having the ( ) in there causes errors for me, and when doing this it comes back as 
"R19[@]:1000000" 
Which isnt what im looking for
But the | head -1 did help that portion.

Comment: Are you using `sh` or `bash` to run this script?

Comment: If bash, then what version?

Comment: 4.3.46(1)-release

Comment: Ah, you typed `"$BASH_REMATCH[@]:1"` not `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"` -- you missed the braces. This is an *array* expansion, so the braces are required.

Comment: Adding those in did change it, however, now it just comes back as all 0's the R19 doesnt show up.

Comment: Are you sure what the value of $1 is right now? `set -- R19` sets $1

Comment: Yes, R19 is my $1, but everytime i run it, it comes back as 000000, so for whatever reason R --> 0 , 1-->0 and 9 -->0 instead of going into the string.

Comment: Did you take the parentheses out of the regular expression? The BASH_REMATCH array gets populated based on the parentheses.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 =~ ^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]$ ]];
 then
  printf "%s00%d00%d/n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
fi

Comment: With no parentheses, we get `BASH_REMATCH[0]="R19"`. With the parenthses, we get `BASH_REMATCH[0]="R19"; BASH_REMATCH[1]="R"; BASH_REMATCH[2]="1"; BASH_REMATCH[3]="9"`. In the printf command, I use `${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}` which uses array indices 1, 2, 3. So, I clearly put the parentheses in my regex for a reason.